# When can a polygon with some edge identifications be embedded in $S^3$?

Tags: general-topology, geometric-topology

Let $P$ be a polygon, and therefore a topological disk.  Suppose we make some identifications on its edges, possibly identifying 2 or more edges of the polygon to a single edge, to get a 2-complex $K$ with a single 2-cell.  Thus, by going around the boundary we get some word in the edge labels and their inverses.  It is well known, for example, that $aba^{-1}b^{-1}$ would give the torus, $aa$ the projective plane, and $abac$ the mobius strip.  Is there any way to tell easily, from this word, whether $K$ can be embedded in $S^3$?

I know it can theoretically be tested by classifying "thickenings" of $K$ and doing some pretty complicated stuff that works for any 2-complex, but I am interested in whether there is a simpler more combinatorial classification in this specific case where we have only a single 2-cell.

If it helps I do not mind assuming that there is only a single vertex, and that there are no subwords of the form $xx^{-1}$ or $x^{-1}x$ for any character $x$, since these assumptions do not seem harmful.

Comment: There's an obstruction in homology coming from Alexander duality: there can be no torsion in $H_1$.

Comment: There are many obstructions coming from the fundamental group: The fundamental group of $K$ is a 1-relator group and many (actually, most) 1-relator groups are not fundamental groups of 3-dimensional manifolds. The simplest examples are (most) Baumslag-Solitar groups.

Comment: Well, I think I can show that either the word must be homologically trivial, or there must be some letter that appears only once.  The proof uses a bit of not entirely trivial 3-manifold topology, but is at least a partial answer.

Comment: @Carl: This partial result does sound interesting. The condition you get is definitely not sufficient though (homological triviality is not nearly enough, for instance, you can easily get torsion in your fundamental group this way, but open subsets of $R^3$ have torsion free fundamental groups).

Comment: Yeah, and I'm not even confidant in that.  I suppose the conclusion is just that even this case is a pretty hard problem.